# Reserved Instance Flexibility in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, billing

I am planning to buy 5 x `t3a.xlarge` reserved instances for 3 years.

After the 3rd year I am planning to buy 3 x `t3a.2xlarge` instances to provide reservation for the `t3a.xlarge` instances whose reservation is still running.

Will the `t3a.2xlarge` provide discount to the `t3a.xlarge` instances?

Does this apply to RDS for `db.t3.xlarge`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Reserved Instance for the `t3a` family will apply to *any* instance type in the `t3a` family.

Therefore, 3 x `t3a.2xlarge` would also count towards 6 x `t3a.xlarge` (because `2xlarge` is double the size of `xlarge`).

However, I wouldn't suggest making plans now for 3 years time because things change quickly in technology. You will probably have more and better options in 3 years.

As an alternative to Reserved Instances, you might instead consider using a [Savings Plan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/savingsplans/latest/userguide/what-is-savings-plans.html). It is more flexible than RIs and, depending upon which option you choose, you can even use it for different instance families.

See:

- [AWS Savings Plans vs Reserved Instances](https://www.gorillastack.com/news/aws-savings-plans-reserved-instances/)
- [Comparison Of Reserved Instances vs. AWS Saving Plans | CloudHealth by VMware](https://www.cloudhealthtech.com/blog/reserved-instances-vs-aws-saving-plan)